# ASP.NET MVC: Redirecting to an Action on a different application

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a copule of MVC apps. I'd like to be able to redirect from one to another? Do I just post to the specific app I'm trying to hit? Is there a way to Html.RedirectToAction on a different app?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What's stopping you from doing the following inside your action?

```
return Redirect("http://www.otherapp.com/product/category");
```

If you don't want to hard code the http://www.otherapp.com then you could put a configuration setting inside your web.config file for it...?

Answer (score 1):

you can use RedirectResult:

```
public ActionResult SomeAction()
{
    // do stuff...
    return Redirect("http://myurl.com");
}
```